# BigQuery, how to define array like field programmatically?

Tags: java, kotlin, google-bigquery

I'm trying to start a datawarehouse project, this is what I would like my schema to look like:

table: event_log
schema:

```
 -> info
    -> user_id: "xyz"
    -> user_properties // <- I want this to be array like
       -> 0
          -> key: "name
          -> value
             -> int_value: null
             -> string_value: "osp"
             ...
       -> 1 // and it goes on
```

The problem is I don't know how to programatically define this array like structure.

I took the idea from here:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pxNrkjBeHpw

here is my code (kotlin using the java google cloud library) so far:

```
    val tableId = TableId.of(datasetName, tableName)

    // First part, general field
    val generalInfoFields = ArrayList<Field>()
    generalInfoFields.add(Field.of("user_id", LegacySQLTypeName.STRING))


    generalInfoFields.add(Field.of("user_properties", {ARRAY LIKE TYPE??}))

    val general_info = Field.of("general_info", LegacySQLTypeName.RECORD, FieldList.of(generalInfoFields))


    // Combine fields and create table
    val tableSchema = Schema.of(general_info)
    val tableDefinition = StandardTableDefinition.of(tableSchema)
    val tableInfo = TableInfo.newBuilder(tableId, tableDefinition).build()
    val table = bigquery.create(tableInfo)



    log.info("dataset created " + dataset.datasetId.dataset)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To define array in BigQuery schema you need to use `Field.Mode.REPEATED` modifier. Check [official docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/nested-repeated).

Your code will look something like this:

```
val arrayField = Field.newBuilder("user_properties", LegacySQLTypeName.RECORD, FieldList.of(<record nested fields here>))
        .setMode(Field.Mode.REPEATED).build()
```

Comment: Yep, I didn't know they were called "repeated" thanks a lot!

Comment: Note that another (potentially easier) option is to execute a `CREATE TABLE` statement; see the [DDL documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/data-definition-language) for more information.